# Typescript compiler incorrectly assuming false value

Tags: typescript

I'm having an issue where the typescript compiler is assuming a variable will always be false, as that was how it was declared.

The code is fairly simple and to introduce the error I have to use an external library to modify the declared variable. In this case, I'm using lodash.

```
import * as _ from 'lodash'; // as an example

let p = ["One", "Two"];
let result = false;

_.each(p, s => {
    if (s === "Two") {
        result = true;
        return;
    }
});

if (result === true) { // Compiler error - this condition will always return false
    // do something.
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=import%20*%20as%20_%20from%20'lodash'%3B%20%2F%2F%20as%20an%20example%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20p%20%3D%20%5B%22One%22%2C%20%22Two%22%5D%3B%0D%0Alet%20result%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A_.each(p%2C%20s%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(s%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22Two%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20result%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(result%20%3D%3D%3D%20true)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20do%20something.%0D%0A%7D)

There have been a few github issues raised:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27910

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27401

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998

These all seem a little more complex that the simple reproducible above. Is this expected behaviour of TypeScript? It seems that it’s falling short here. I'm pretty sure this didn’t happen in version 2.

Is there a work-around? Am I doing something wrong?

Currently I'm using TypeScript version 3.2.1

Comment: Workaround: use `let result = _.some(p, s => s === 'Two');` :)

Comment: You could use `for... of`

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, that would certainly be cleaner. And more elegant. However, I was using the example more for demonstration than actualy real life usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
let result = false as boolean;
```

The reason why typescript complains is that it thinks that it is smarter than it is, i.e. it sees that you assign `false` value to the `result` variable, but it *does not see* the operation in the callback function.

I don't really know why the Typescript team did things this way. They definitely had their reasons, but they also missed the case from your example.

Probably TS considered that the operation `_.each` is asynchronous because of the callback, but of course not every operation that involves a callback is asyncronous.

Comment: Thanks Nurbol. That fixes the issue. Allthough I'm still not convinced the issue should need to be fixed.

Comment: As for the reasoning, it's covered here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998

Comment: @NeilWatson Oh there are so many things that are not perfect in TS (just like in life). But overall it's good.

Comment: @Aaron can you please point to exact location of the issue? I am curious.